# Keep button selected or highlighted at specific tabbar selectedindex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I created a button and i placed this over de tabbar with [this guide](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/).

I want this button to be highlighted/selected only if selectedIndex is 2. When the selectedIndex is 0 1 3 4 i don't want the to have its normal state. Is this possible?

I tried the following and it highlights the button, but a soon as I click the button, the highlight disappears and doesn't return.

```
if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2) {
    button.selected = YES;
    button.highlighted = YES;
}else {      
    button.selected = NO;
    button.highlighted = NO;
}
```

If necessary, the code to load the button over the tabbar:

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
buttonFrame.size.height = 55;
buttonFrame.size.width = 64;
buttonFrame.origin.x = 128;
buttonFrame.origin.y = 424;
button.frame = buttonFrame;
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonhighlight.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonhighlight.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_tabBarController.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you call your button highlighting code? I think you need to call it each time a tab is touched (Implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` to know when the user switch tab).

Example:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController { 

    if([viewController.title isEqualToString:@"View controller 1"]) {

        NSLog(@"View controller 1 was selected");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Some other view controller was selected");

     }
}
```

Comment: I call it within `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` 
Could you give an example, been trying to make it work but when I use `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController1 { NSLog (@"VC1 selected");}` it runs the nslog code for every viewcontroller I select.

Comment: Yes it will show the same output because you have no condition specified. I have edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the answer.

I had to change a few things in **my code** to get it to work. Maybe this will help others: 

First reason it didn't work is that i changed the name SecondViewController to something else. For some reason it couldn't pickup the `viewController.title`, even tho everything else worked fine. Creating a new file with xib and adding that fixed that problem.

Other reason why it didn't work: I used the button to set `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2`, I had to remove the button, and to get the highlighted effect I add an image subview when the condition changes.

Answer (score 0):

iv added this to my custom tabbar.m file.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)theTabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[theTabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
NSLog(@"Tab index = %u", indexOfTab);

if (indexOfTab == 0) {
    [button setSelected:false];
}
if (indexOfTab == 1) {
    [button setSelected:false];
}

if (indexOfTab == 3) {
        [button setSelected:false];
    }
if (indexOfTab == 4) {
        [button setSelected:false];

    }
}


- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
        [button setSelected:true];

        [self setSelectedIndex:2];}
```

this works for me, hope it helps  others ....